# Adding Dynamic Numbers at the end of Dynamic Variables with Subjected Value

Tags: matlab

```
load( lapFileSource, 'UntitledMeta_Data' );%My n*1 Cell array
p=12;
j=1;
if isempty(MetaData{p})%Checks if Cell is Empty 
    %Do Nothing
else    
    for j=1:size(MetaData)%if Not Load that Value in Load_{j} and so on
        eval(['Load_' num2str(j)''=MetaData{p}])
        %Load_(j)=MetaData{p};
        p=p+1;
    end
end
```

This results in this error:

> "Error: File: File_Converter_OldtoNew.m Line: 186 Column: 31
>   The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment."

Comment: Any time you are using `eval` you should think there is a problem with your code! Why not do `Load_=cell2mat(MetaData)` or something similar?

Comment: I know the Values till 11 rows of MetaData. While from 12th row it can Change, for example some Files Can have only 12th Row, while other will have 12th, 13th,14th. Now I want to assign Load1 = 12th Value, Load2=13th value in MetaData and So on..

Comment: `eval` evaluates a string. Should be ['Load_' num2str(j) '=MetaData{p};']

Comment: O yes, I was Assigning the Raw Value rather than Evaluating. My bad. Thanks for the Help. @macduf